# Required to repeat 'is' when specifying two attributions?

Tags: repetition, copular-verbs

I am seeing that I often leave out copula when connecting two clauses. Like:

> A notation is fixed but the performance variable.

I have the feeling this is a mistake coming from my German mother tongue. Is the previous sentence correct English, or should it rather repeat the 'is':

> A notation is fixed but the performance *is* variable.

**A second example:**

> The function may be written into the control component or visible from the outside.

vs.

> The function may be written into the control component or *be* visible from the outside.

vs.

> The function may be written into the control component or *may be* visible from the outside.

Comment: ... may either be written into the control, or visible from the outside?

Answer (score -3):

A notation is fixed but the performance is variable.
This is better, but still rather far from ideal.

*Try this: Although a notation is fixed but the performance is variable.*

[ 2 ]
The function may be written into the control component or may be visible from the outside.
The above is okay, but not 100%
try this:
*The function may either be written into the control component or it be ensured that it is visible from the outside.*

Comment: I'm not asking a stylistic question, but whether one can, technically, omit the verbs or not

Comment: one can, technically, omit the verbs or not ? Answer, no one can not omit verbs in simple prose. Poets may use such liberty though.

Comment: In German you can, therefore I want a definite answer in English. I'm not omitting verbs, I'm omitting the repetition of verbs. This is for an academic text.